# SQL Top 10 Sales Every Month

Tags: sql, statistics

Greeting all. I have a SQL 2008 express database, lets name is tbl_Merchant, similar as following:

```
Merchant | Sales | Month
Comp.1      100     1
Comp.2      230     1
Comp.3      120     1
Comp.1      200     2
Comp.2      130     2
Comp.3      240     2
Comp.1      250     3
  .          .      .
  .          .      .
  .          .      .
```

I need to find the top 10 merchant with sales every month over 12 months.

It is very easy if it is just one month.

```
SELECT TOP 10 
       Merchant, 
       Sales, 
       Month
FROM   tbl_Merchant
WHERE  Month = 1
ORDER BY Sales DESC
```

But I am stuck if I wan to find them over 12 months. I need to display 120 merchants, which are top 10 sales merchant of each month. Currently my solution is to union 12 tables from month 1 to 12 together but I don't think it is a good way.

Can any one kindly give me any suggestion?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which SQL (MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLServer, etc) are you using?

Comment: @MarkBannister: `TOP 10` indicates SQL Server or Sybase (both `T-SQL`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Valid for Sql Server 2005+

Try this for overall:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
       Merchant, 
       SUM(Sales) Sales
FROM   tbl_Merchant
WHERE  Month BETWEEN 1 and 12
GROUP BY Merchant
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

**OR**

if you need details per month for top 10 **PER MONTH**

```
;WITH MonthsCTE(m) as
(
    SELECT 1 m
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT m+1
    FROM MonthsCTE
    WHERE m < 12
)
SELECT m [Month], t.*
FROM MonthsCTE
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 10
       Merchant, 
       SUM(Sales) Sales
    FROM   tbl_Merchant
    WHERE  Month = MonthsCTE.m
    GROUP BY Merchant
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
) t
```

Comment: this is not correct: SUM(Sales) Sales. Read the question. Sales are already sum for each merchant/month.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
select * from
(SELECT Merchant, 
        Sales, 
        Month,
        row_number () over (partition by Month order by Sales desc) rn
 FROM   tbl_Merchant
 WHERE  Month between 1 and 12) v
where rn <= 10
order by Month, Sales desc
```

(Should work in SQLServer; not sure about Sybase.)

Answer (score 0):

Can try the following:

```
SELECT top 10 Merchant,
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN Month(ta.dt) = '01' THEN Sales END),0) AS "Jan Sales",
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN Month(ta.dt) = '02' THEN Sales END),0) AS "Feb Sales",
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN Month(ta.dt) = '03' THEN Sales END),0) AS "Mar Sales",
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN Month(ta.dt) = '04' THEN Sales END),0) AS "Apr Sales",
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN Month(ta.dt) = '05' THEN Sales END),0) AS "May Sales",
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN Month(ta.dt) = '06' THEN Sales END),0) AS "Jun Sales",
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN Month(ta.dt) = '07' THEN Sales END),0) AS "Jul Sales",
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN Month(ta.dt) = '08' THEN Sales END),0) AS "Aug Sales",
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN Month(ta.dt) = '09' THEN Sales END),0) AS "Sep Sales",
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN Month(ta.dt) = '10' THEN Sales END),0) AS "Oct Sales",
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN Month(ta.dt) = '11' THEN Sales END),0) AS "Nov Sales",
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN Month(ta.dt) = '12' THEN Sales END),0) AS "Dec Sales"

FROM tbl_Merchant ORDER BY Sales DESC
```

Top 10 sales of every month will be displayed as different columns by month.

Hope it helps u.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Top 10 
         SaleID, 
         sum(Salelines) As LINESUM
Into #TOP10sales
from salestable
group by SaleID
order by sum(Salelines) asc;

Then confirm the sales are top 10

select * 
from #TOP10sales;

Then.

Select field..
       field..
       field..
from #TOP10sales 
Inner Join salestable on #TOP10sales.ID = salestable.ID;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select top 10 Merchant, sum(Sales) from tbl_Merchant group by Merchant order by sum(Sales) desc
```

I'm more postgresql guy, but i think it could work without (or with little) modification in mssql

Comment: hmm... why -1 for this answer?

Answer (score -1):

Details per month for top 10 PER MONTH can be derived using this query too

select merchant,SUM(sales)Total_sales,month as Monthofyear
from tbl_Merchant
group by month,merchant,sales
order by month,sales desc

Comment: Sorry, it only lists out the top 10. It is not I want.